# Struggle with floor- and ceiling-functions in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, calculations, graphs

Could anyone help me with this struggle? I don't get, why the floor- and ceil-functions in the axis-environment of pgfplots and in floating text differ from each other. Aren't they both processed by PGF?
[image]

```
\documentclass[border = 3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot [domain = 0:10, color = blue] {floor(0)};
      \addplot [domain = 0:10, color = red] {ceil(0)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  $\mathrm{floor}(0)=\pgfmathparse{floor(0)}\pgfmathresult$,\quad
  $\mathrm{ceil}(0)=\pgfmathparse{ceil(0)}\pgfmathresult$

\end{document}
```

Comment: No they don't use the same engine. Pgfplots turn on the `fpu` library by default.

Comment: @percusse, then it looks like a bug in `fpu` doesn't it ? `floor(0)`  should never return `-1`. I tried `floor(0.0001)`  and its does return `0` for the graph.

Comment: `ceil(2)` in the TikZ picture is also interesting... and actually also the `ceil(0)` which I overlooked from the OP. Clearly there is something wrong here !

Comment: @jfbu Might be as well. I didn't test it.

Comment: @percusse the `TikZ/pgf` manual contains a section on the `fpu` library, but I find no mention of `floor/ceil`. I suspect it is to be understood that the list of math functions is to be found elsewhere in the manual and is not repeated there. Am I correct ? (will suppress that comment later)

Comment: @jfbu Christian Feuersanger, author of pgfplots and coauthor of TikZ, maintains this library in parallel with pgfplots. Sometimes he pushes updates to library in benefit of both as pgfplots uses pgf as a backend but maybe he forgot to update the manual.

Comment: Oh my bad... I fear I tripped up the floor/ceiling functions recently. I worked on them right before PGF 3.0.1 was released, and I must have been stopped thinking at that time. I know that the floating point unit had no focus on these methods and had just a rudimentary version of it. Anyway, it seems like this is simply a bug. I will take care of it.

Comment: A  workaround could be to write `use fpu=false` into the axis options, i.e. `\begin{axis}[use fpu=false]`. This might work if you have a relatively small data range (it works for this minimal example).

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: Many thanks! The hint about deactivating fpu worked very well for my issues!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is a bug in PGF (in the floating point unit).

A workaround is to write `use fpu=false` in the axis options, i.e. `\begin{axis}[use fpu=false]`. This workaround is valid for relatively small number ranges, only -- such as in your MWE.

I will take care of the bug.